# Para serve ExampleUnitTest e ExampleInstrumentedTest no Android Studio?

Tags: android

Olá, eu estou aprendendo a desenvolver no Android e gostaria de saber a utilidade desses arquivos e como o Android usa eles.

Notei que alguns aplicativos as vezes não possum esses arquivos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

São classes de testes. ExampleUnitTest é para testes unitários, são testes locais e não precisam de emulador ou device para rodar. Você pode testar métodos nessa classe, além de criar novas classes de testes unitários. Exemplo:

```
@Test
public void get_current_user_test() {
    User mUser = new User();
    mUser.setName("joao");
    mUser.setEmail("joao@hotmail.com");
    mUser.setUserId("123");
    User mUser_two;
    UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
    mUser_two = userDao.getCurrentUser("joao", "joao@hotmail.com", "123");

    assertEquals(mUser.getEmail(), mUser_two.getEmail());
    assertEquals(mUser.getName(), mUser_two.getName());
}
```

Esse método acima testa se o usuário que você criou é igual ao usuário que está em uma classe do seu projeto por exemplo.

ExampleInstrumentedTest é classe para testes instrumentais, e mais uma vez, você pode criar suas próprias classes. Esse tipo de teste precisa de um emulador ou device e em background ela instala e roda seu app. Ela serve para testes de UI, mas também pode ser utilizada para testar contexto e dependências.

Exemplo:

```
Context mMockContext;
SharedPreferences preferences;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mMockContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    preferences = mMockContext.getSharedPreferences(Contract.SETTINGS_PREF, 0);
}

@Test
public void test_encode_string() {
    String from = "<p>htmltext</p>";
    String to = "htmltext\n\n";
    from = NewsFeedDao.encodeString(from);

    Assert.assertEquals(from, to);
}
```

Neste método acima é testado o Encoding de uma string de texto recuperada de um feed de notícias do site XPTO.